Trailer wheels with wedges
My 22 year old tires had to be replaced on my 34-year-old boat trailer. (If this question is not appropriate for this group, please delete it.) Because I thought I understood the situation, I removed three tires and took them to the tire store. I was surprised two stores told me that didn't work on that type of wheel. The last store put three tires on my rims without issue. I described my problem with them and they advised me to look at the last tire remaining on the trailer, which I had left on to support the trailer along with a jack.
Here's my concern. When I went to put the new tires on, the nuts hold a wedge with a slant on one side that touches the hub? and a more chunky side that is supposed to seat. The problem is the thing doesn't seat as deeply as I think it should. It kind of sticks up over the edge. Am I supposed to hit it with a hammer or something to get it to seat? I looked at the remaining, original tire and I'm suspicious about its install as well.
I wonder if anyone has a clue what I'm talking about. If I had a name for these strange non-lug nuts, I could google the part and [![enter image description here][2]][2]ask a more coherent question. Thanks.

Does it look something like the link here? If not please take 1 or more photos of the wheel that's still on the trailer and its lugs and add the photos to your question. (Click EDIT below your question, then use the picture icon (mountains/sun) to add the photo.) See here: https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8759/16434597553_3a6e43eea3_n.jpg

It's unclear to me whether the question is about tires fitting wheels, or wheels fitting hubs. For example "I removed three tires".

MTA, It doesn't really look like that. I'll take a picture tomorrow. It's along that line.  Weather Vane, I'm not surprised you're confused. I only removed three at a time, because I had to keep the trailer up. I had a jack on one side and one of four tires on the other. I now have three back on---all sketchy.

MTA, thanks for the photo instructions. I didn't mean to post it twice.  I feel like the edge should be flush with the non-slanted part. I'm very nervous to drive this trailer. I've learned that the mount is called Dexter Rim clamp. Thanks for any advice.

Now that you know what it is by name, you will be able to find info about use and maintenance from sources online, including videos.

Don't worry about it.  There is no impact damage.  Whatever the design, it appears to be in its original state.  Do not hit anything with a hammer.
The real concern is the rust on the bolt.  I owned boats and a trailer for years and know how easily old bolts break when exposed to water.  Have the shop remove and replace the bolts with an impact wrench.

I won't use the hammer (again). All the wheels and stuff look undamaged. I'll wire brush things tomorrow and grease stuff. The bolts and wedges are removable.. None of the washers---the Derrick wedges--settle down into the space beneath them on the non-slanted side. The slanted side holds nicely, but the part that touches the hub wants to rise above the space that appears to be designed for it. The only original tire I left on that I was able to compare, the wedges were also raised up above the hub, but it seems wrong.  I'll replace the bolts---good to know!

I ended up hiring a man who told me the wedges don't go flush, so I think I was on the right track. He said my tires are like house trailer tires. Thanks for everything, all.
